# Dimension of endomorphisms subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $V$ an $\mathbb R$-vector space with finite dimension $n$ ($n \neq 0$).
We know that all endomorphisms $f$ on $E$ can be written as a linear combination of some projectors of $E$. Otherwise: if $\mathcal P_E$ is the set of all projectors of $E$ then $\text{Span}(\mathcal P_E)= \mathcal L(E)$.

1. **Here's a question that attempts to generalize this result:**
   Let $F$ a vector subspace of $V$ and $\mathcal P_F$ the set of projectors $p$  of $E$ such that $\text{Im} p \subset F$ and $\mathcal V_F=\text{Span}(\mathcal P_F)$.
   Determine $\dim(\mathcal V_F)$
2. **Here's an other question which is not far from this topic
   :** Determine $\dim (\overline{\mathcal V}_F)$ where $\overline{\mathcal V}_F = \text{Span} (\overline{\mathcal P}_F)$ and $\overline{\mathcal P}_F$ is the set of projectors $p$  of $E$ such that $\text{Im} p = F$

I am interested in the second question (the first being more accessible).

Comment: Are 'projectors' here meant to be *orthogonal* (self-adjoint), i.e. $p^2=p=p^*$?

Comment: Ok, surely not, because then they would generate only self-adjoint linear transformations.

Comment: @Berci : for me a projector is an endomorphism $p$ such that $p^2=p$.

Comment: Can you mimic the proof of ${\rm Span}(\mathcal P_E)=\mathcal L(E)$ to prove that ${\rm Span}(\mathcal P_F)=\{A\in\mathcal L(E)\mid {\rm Im\,}A\subseteq F\}$?

Comment: @Berci : Yes : if $A \in \text{Span} (\mathcal P_F)$ it's easy to see that $\text{Im}\,A \subset F$. Conversly, for all $j \in\{1,\cdots,n\}$ and $ i \in \{1,\cdots,m\}$  considere the elementary matrix $E_{ij}$ and the matrix $P_{ij}=E_{ii} + E_{ij}$   if $i \neq j$  and $P_{ii} = E_{ii} $. Then, $P_{ij}$ is a projector matrix ($P_{ij}^2=P_{ij}$ ) and it is clear that $\text{Im} P_{ij} \subset F$. The number of theses matrix is $mn$ and there are linearly independants, so the dimesnion of our space is $\geq mn$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the second question, it seems easiest to first look at the difference between two such projectors. Such a function $f:V\to F$ vanishes on $F$ (both projectors are identity there) and has its image contained in$~F$, so in particular $f^2=0$. Conversely if $f$ has those properties and $p$ is a projector with $\operatorname{Im}p=F$, then $(p+f)^2=p^2+pf+fp+f^2=p+f$ (since $p^2=p$, $pf=f$, and the last two terms vanish), so $p+f$ is a projector, and its image is easily checked to be$~F$. Therefore the set of such differences$~f$ is a vector subspace$~S$ of the space of endomorphisms of$~V$, whose dimension is $\dim(V/F)\dim(F)$. The set$~\overline{\mathcal P}_F$ of projectors is a translate of this subspace$~S$ by some$~p$, which gives an affine space; the span of$~\overline{\mathcal P}_F$ contains $S$ and also$~p$, while $p\notin S$ (unless $\dim F=0$). The presence of $p$ increases the dimension by$~1$. All in all the dimension of the span of$~\overline{\mathcal P}_F$ is $\dim(V/F)\dim(F)+1$ (unless $\dim F=0$, in which case it is$~0$).